# Plotting points conditionally using cluster number in qgis

Tags: qgis, clustering, spatial-query

I have a set of locations such that there are partitioned into five clusters, I used the categorized property under styles to differentiate points belonging to different clusters using different colors but I want to run queries such that I can select and display the points on the map according to cluster numbers using the queries in qgis.

Comment: Once you have applied the categorized style to your layer, you should see the different categories into the TOC (Table of contents = layers list). Each category is fitted with a tick box that you can tick or untick to display / hide points belonging to each category.

Comment: @wiltomap thanks for that I know that but what i really want is to implement this using queries and not manual selection

Comment: You can select points via a query. These points will then be highlighted with the selection color specified for your QGIS instance. I don't know how to display and hide points at the same time via a query...

Comment: @wiltomap - Consider posting your comments as an answer =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possibilities come to me:

1. **Categorized styling**. Once you have applied the categorized style to your layer, you should see the different categories into the TOC. Each category is fitted with a tick box that you can tick or untick to display / hide points belonging to each category.
2. **Query via Select by expression**. You can also select points via a query (via Field Calculator). These points will then be highlighted with the selection color specified for your QGIS instance. I don't know how to display and hide points at the same time via a query...

Comment: How and where to execute the select query so that it chooses according to cluster numbers?

Comment: Use Field Calculator (I've updated my post to add this).